# flutter setState is popping the page when using Navigator.push and when using Navigator.of it doesnt work at all

Tags: javascript, android, flutter

I wrote simple code of three pages app and in the third page when it  uses `SetState' it return to the second page but only in the third page it happened , when I use 'setState' in the second page it work fine .
I also tried to use  'Navigator.of.push' to navigate between the pages but then the setState just didnt do anything
here an example of my code

```
String check="go to next page";
String check2="state1";
Widget page3()
{
  
  return return  FlatButton(
      child:Text(check2)
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[100])),
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: (){
       setState((){check2="state3"});
          
         });
 }
Widget Profile()
{
 return  FlatButton(
      child:Text(check)
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[100])),
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: (){
       setState((){check2="state3"});
       Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page3()),
          )      
         });
}
Widget Biuld(BuildContext context)
{
 return return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body:
   FlatButton(
      child:Text("press to start")
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[100])),
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: (){
       Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => profile()),
          ); 
               
         }));
 }
```

and the result I get is that when pressing the first button it go to page2 and when I press the second  button it change the second button text and go to page three, but then when I press the button on page three it goes back to the second page . when using navgitor.of it doesn't return to the second page but it doesn't change the text either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing why you are using the set state method before changing the page with the Navigator.push. SetState should be used to change the state of data on the page you are currently in, not to be used as a "global" data storage.

I suggest you a couple of alternatives:

- use a "Top level" provider shared by all the pages and update its value: [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)
- use a local database [SQLite](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)

EDIT: Probably this might help you [Managing state using provider](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/managing-the-state-of-a-widget-using-provider-flutter-6b5090f18875)

Comment: it just an example in general it changing the ui ,what you mean by before changing the page? I am editing variable and I want to refresh the change

Comment: maybe each function should be in difference class?

Comment: the set state is usually called to update the UI after a change of a local field of the widget. However, the state is not persistent, if you destroy the widgets by changing page (calling Navigator.push) also the state got destroyed. In this way the value change of "check2" isn't preserved. In practice check2 will remain state1 if you call navigator.push after the set state. I hope I made myself clearer.

If you need to keep changes to check2 values, I suggest you use one of the solutions I proposed. In particular, the provider can be very useful

Comment: ok thanks in addition in order to solve this I had to create separate class

Answer (score 0):

you need to have separate  class each one with build function so the context will be new each page , that way you have to create statefull class and then another class with the page